# Avoid not necessary insert subclass when insert with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, automapper, automapping

I have this objects :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Locality Locality { get; set; }
}

public class Locality
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

In the Entity Framework model, I have this `PERSON, ADDRESS, LOCALITY`

I'm doing this :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PERSON>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, ADDRESS>();
    .ForMember(x => x.Locality, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

When I try to insert a new `Person` in the database I see with the profiler (Entity Framework Profiler) an insert on Locality table too. I just want a insert a User that's it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you describe the User class/table, or is person=user?

Comment: Sorry typo (corrected). Thanks,

Comment: What is exact contents of your Entity Framework data classes after mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `State` on the `Locality` in the new `Person` to `EntityState.Unchanged`.

```
 context.ObjectStateManager
     .ChangeObjectState
     (newPerson.Locality, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
```